# Translate variable name on Smarty foreach loop with gettext

Tags: php, foreach, smarty, gettext

I've a problem with Smarty 3 foreach loop and gettext translations.
In my controller i intercept the variables from a MySQL database and then i create an array:

CONTROLLER:

```
array_categories[] = array(
            'name_cat_it' => $name_cat_it,
            'name_cat_en' => $name_cat_en,
);
$smarty->assign('array_cat', $array_categories);
```

TEMPLATE:

```
{foreach name=categorie key=key item=value from=$array_cat}
{$value.name_cat_it}
{/foreach}
```

Till now everything is ok, but i would like to do something like this:

```
{foreach name=categorie key=key item=value from=$array_cat}
{$value.name_cat_{$lang}}
{/foreach}
```

$lang can be 'it' o 'en'.
Is this possible inside a foreach loop?
Outside the loop i have no problem doing this for the meta title or the meta description.

Thanks a lot!

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a temporal variable to compose the name:

```
{$name_lang='name_cat_'|cat:$lang}    
{foreach name=categorie key=key item=value from=$array_cat}
{$value.$name_lang}
{/foreach}
```